# Unable to edit a dynamic component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

I am creating a dynamic component in usual way as follows.

```
const formRowFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(FormRowComponent);
const { instance: formRowComponent } = this.newComponents.createComponent(formRowFactory);
formRowComponent.name = categoryName;
```

I store its index elsewhere so I can retrieve the component

```
const component = this.newComponents.get(index);
```

I then want to edit the name and I can not do it. It does not let me access the instance or there is no function to alter it.

[image]

So how do you do it? By the way, it is so easy to edit content children in Angular. Why so tough with the dynamic ones?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because when you write `this.newComponents.get(index)` you receive back the **ViewRef** and not the **ComponentRef**. I maintain a separate array with my dynamically created component references to access them later.

[Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#get)